# Is Linux kernel TCP/IP stack zero copy?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, ip

I‘m reading the code of the implementation of linux TCP/IP stack. After the application calls `send` syscall, the kernel uses `copy_from_user` to copy the data the app wants to send into the kernel. After this, in each stage of the kernel execution (such as TCP stack, IP stack, fragmentation .etc), will the kernel copy the user data again?

I looked through the linux kernel code, but I haven't been able to fully figure out the problem because it's so complex.

Comment: Does the NIC do scatter-gather DMA or does it require the header and data to be a single contiguous buffer?  See the problem of a simple answer? The kernel has to work for all devices.